# Replace HTML tag(</br>) with Alt+Enter in Excel

Tags: html, vba, excel

I am working on VBA, but I have one problem of how to replace a tag of HTML with Alt+Enter. For example, If I type a sentence: Hello World. In shell of Excel, I press on Alt+Enter to Enter between Hello and World. Then I want to copy it to somewhere else that after I copied it shows like: HelloWorld. Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

The `<br>` tag in HTML just gives you a line break.

In VBA, you can accomplish the same thing using the `vbNewLine` constant.

The [`Replace` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt3szac5.aspx) will come in handy for this.

```
Dim input As String
input = "Hello<br>World!"

Dim result As String
result = Replace$(input, "<br>", vbNewLine)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Excel formula:

`=SUBSTITUTE(B4, "<br>", "` Alt+Enter `")`