# Prevent reformatting of characters when changing line in cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a cell with formatted text containing a certain substring that I want to replace with a line change. The substring is [enterkey] with the square brackets. It is a variant of this question [Replace HTML tag(</br>) with Alt+Enter in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874391/replace-html-tag-br-with-altenter-in-excel) but I want to keep formatting after changing the line.

[image]

The code I am using is a simple replace where rng2 is the input and output cell:

```
rng2.Value = Replace(rng2.Value, "[enterkey]", Chr(10))
```

**My Question**

How can I prevent that code from copying the format of the line above when inserting a line feed? I want it to conserve the format AS IT IS and simply insert a line feed, like shown in the picture.

---

More info

I'm actually converting to HTML and back. I didn't want to add unnecessary details but if people really want to know, it's because I'm storing the values in an Access database and I want to keep cell formatting. When retrieving info from Access, I want to have the proper formatting again. This question only concerns the conversion back. See below picture for full details.

[image]

Comment: Probably need to run a routine like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644566/excel-vba-set-bold-specific-text-of-string-into-the-cell) on the cell after doing the replace. May need to use `Instr` to get the position of `Chr(10)` to know which characters to make bold or not.

Comment: I think pre-processing the string to make [enterkey] the same format as the text after it might be more efficient than post-processing it, because then the wanted format would be lost. Maybe something like copying the format of the first char after [enterkey] and making it the same. That way after replacing, the format wouldn't change. How could I go about that?

Comment: Will it always **bold** first line and *italic* second line?

Comment: No; there may be 1 line, there may be 10 lines. There will be bold, italics, font, font colors. Any format you can think of putting in an Excel cell, really. What it really is, is a HTML string where I replaced <br> with [enterkey], and then change the HTML to a rich text format. I had to change the <br> because when changing format it would cause a cell change, not a line change. It works fine, and results in something like the input cell (but much longer usually)

Comment: okay. That's an *entirely* different set of issues then the example you posted ... let me test some more from the idea I am building

Comment: I'll give a more complete picture under the question.

Comment: the other interesting thing is that when I run `rng2.Value = Replace(rng2.Value, "[enterkey]", Chr(10))` against my cell it does not keep any formatting. It leaves it all as plain text.

Comment: Really? That's strange. All formatting disappears for you? See my edit btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I got something that works.

This code:

```
Sub ReplaceEnterKey()

Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng2 = Range("O15")

Dim iChr As Integer
iChr = InStr(1, rng2.Value, "[e") 'find beginning of first occurence of "[enterkey]"

Do Until iChr = 0 'loop until no more occurences found

    rng2.Characters(iChr, 10).Delete 'remove found occurrence of "[enterkey]" - 10 characters
    rng2.Characters(iChr, 0).Insert Chr(10) 'insert carriage return where "[enterkey]" used to be

    iChr = InStr(1, rng2.Value, "[e") 'look for next occurence

Loop

End Sub
```

Created this result. `N15` was original `O15`.

[image]

Comment: Excellent. That's exactly what was needed. In retrospect, you see that I didn't need to share all that additional information ;)

Comment: @DavidG. Hindsight is always 20/20. Your 2nd comment got me to this place. I had a much simpler solution in mind based on your original example, which did turn out to be incomplete.